# No Issues Visible in Jira Project

Tags: jira

I have a Jira project and noticed yesterday that I was unable to see any new issues created. I then made the mistake of moving my issues between 2 projects. I've moved them all back to the original project and now they have disappeared (I can't even search for them).

I can see that they are still in the project somewhere as when viewing the workflow the number of issues appears next to the issue type (e.g In Progress (35)).

- There are no Issue Security Levels in the project.
- I have checked that I have browse project rights.
- I am a project admin.
- I have checked that the issue types are assigned to the project.
- I have re-indexed the database.
- The project has one assigned workflow scheme, which is a Jira
  Simplified workflow.

I am totally lost, can anyone help!?

Comment: And what is the screen where you expect to see your issues but don't get any?

Comment: In the Search for Issues screen, there are simply no issues. I have another project which is working correctly and I can search issues for that one.

On the Project Board, it just says there are no issues found and to check the board configuration - I've checked the filter query and statuses, but there are apparently no issues assigned to any status, even though I have assigned them (I've checked this by looking at the workflow)

Thanks!

Comment: What JQL do you use? Do you get any errors if you run the integrity check? https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver071/using-the-database-integrity-checker-802592958.html

Comment: @GlennV 

Integrity Check has raised no errors. For the board filter, JQL is: `project = SOL ORDER BY priority DESC, Rank ASC` and there is no JQL used in the issue search, so it's showing all issues available to me.

Comment: From what you describe it doesn't seem to make much sense. Maybe some screenshots could point out what's wrong.